# Why won't this page load into an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have some html that loads a page into an iframe. This works fine with this page, for example:

https://seandavi.github.io/

However, a page like this:

https://twitter.com/seandavis12/

results in an empty iframe. I suspect this has to do with the page from twitter being rendered in parts using javascript, but I am not sure how to force the page to display in an iframe. Any suggestions?

Environments I have tested: chrome & safari on mac OS

Minimal example:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <iframe src="https://seandavi.github.io"></iframe>
    <iframe src="https://twitter.com/seandavis12/"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: show us the code you are using so we can attempt to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't be able to embed Twitter in an iframe - they have [HTTP headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors) set which your browser sees and prevents the iframe content from being rendered.

If you open your browser console you will be able to see it being blocked:

[image]

Twitter will allow you to embed a specific tweet on a page, however, but you must follow their guide on how to do this: https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-tweets

Comment: Thanks. The general takeway for me was to look in the console. Other websites have other causes (eg., "Refused to display 'https://support.bioconductor.org/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.")

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is you can't use iframe/frame/embed/object or any other regular embedding html tag.

Most large company websites that aren't simply static, video streaming (ex. youtube), or informational, will likely have the "X-Frame-Options" set to 'sameorigin'. This is known as a Frame-Killer, disabling iframes/frames/etc from embedding content because they are highly vulnerable to being Click-Jacked.

[Check out the security section here in Dev Moz](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Other_embedding_technologies)

Oftentimes, high profile companies with desirable endpoints and webpages will provide alternate embedding options or even API's that allow you to safely request access for displaying their resources.